# Is modal expansion a user friendly pattern?

Tags: modal

I have a problem whether to have everything in one modal, or have one after the other. Any help would be appreciated. Please pic the option that makes sense. Any other solution would be awesome too :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**I’d choose option 2, the “wizard” pattern.**

Your second option allows the user to digest the UI in chunks and maintain comprehension of that screen until they are ready to progress.

If a significant portion of your UI changes, it can cause the user to have to reprocess everything to evaluate what just changed if they weren’t paying close enough attention.

Using the wizard approach, you hide the details of “well you picked option 2, so BAM! here’s more fields to complete.” Picking a value in a drop down is not a typical trigger to cause a significant UI change, so it will likely be unexpected. Isolating these dynamic fields will make your application appear more fluid.

Comment: Thanks so much, Max. I appreciate the help. I was pondering over this for a long time, and settled for this option for the same reason you have given here :)

Comment: I suppose you should rename the button to *Next*, otherwise users might think that this will start the process.

Comment: This might be the right answer sometimes, but because the question lacks context, you can't be sure. For instance, Option 1 would be better if the user needs to reference previously selected items or information. With Option 2 they would need to remember their previous selections between screens.

Comment: @Zenon That's a good point. If the user still needs to see the information, this might not be the optimal solution unless you reproduce the needed information in the next view in some way. You're right—it's hard to tell if this is the optimal solution without knowing the specific use case.

Comment: Another point if you choose option 2: in virtually all cases you should have a way of going back to the original "Option 1/Option 2" choice in case the user sees the new screen and realises they chose the wrong one.